# Chromium not displaying the correct font used in CSS

Tags: fonts, chrome, elementary-os

When trying to reproduce a given webpage on a CSS course, Chromium always seems to revert to a generic `serif`, `sans-serif` or `monospace` font even though I've used, for example, Impact, Helvetica and Courier New. It's not the first time I've noticed this, but it is much more obvious with a font like Impact.

[image]

The right-hand image is what the page is supposed to look like; my Chromium display is on the left. I'm not shooting for attractiveness, just reproduction.

I am using Chromium 65.0 on elementary 0.3.2 Freya. I know the browser has access to more fonts because most other webpages look fine. Is this is a general issue where Ubuntu just has its own fonts? I know Impact was originally a Windows typeface, but surely it is still web-safe!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I just did not have any Microsoft fonts on my system. I needed to `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, update my font cache with `sudo fc-cache -f -v` and reboot my system, and it works.